# How to install activeperl for windows 32 bit pc

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl

How to install activeperl for windows 32 bit pc? Facing issues in installing as the vversions 5.16.3.1603 and 5.18.1.1800 supports 64 bit and not 32 bit.

Comment: Be more specific and post the issue or error you are facing

Answer (score 1):

You can download the 32-bit version for Windows at http://strawberryperl.com/

Answer (score 1):

The 32bit community binaries are now behind a paywall. You have to be part of the ActiveState Platform, teams tier, to gain access to legacy builds.

The site states: "if you need 32-bit or other older/legacy versions, they are available through our new ActiveState Platform by subscribing to at least Team Tier. See pricing here."

Since the teams tear is $912/yr. I would suggest using strawberry Perl as @kurdtpage mentioned for 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

The [download page](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) for ActivePerl has links for 32-bit (x86) and 64-bit (64-bit, x64) installers for both 5.16.3.1603 and 5.18.1.1800, with the 32-bit versions apparently differentiated by the presence of "x86" in the name of the downloadable file for 32-bit systems.

I don't have a 32-bit machine to try installing these files on, but unless I'm missing something, it looks like they do have separate 32-bit versions available for download.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this site: https://softradar.com/activeperl/

I use that site for much downloads.